# Centos apache webserver throwing 403 error

Tags: linux, apache, centos, webserver

I am just trying to learn CentOS and installed apache server on it. But when I trying `curl` on my local ip I am getting `403 error`. Intens user has sudo user.

Installed apache server with this user only. I don't know how to give me access to run the webserver.

```
    [Inten@localhost ~]$ hostname -I | awk '{print $1}'
10.0.2.15
[Intens@localhost ~]$ curl 10.0.2.15:80
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>403 Forbidden</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Forbidden</h1>
<p>You don't have permission to access /
on this server.<br />
</p>
<p>Additionally, a 403 Forbidden
error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.</p>
</body></html>
```

Permissions on folder

```
[Intens@localhost ~]$ ls -ld /etc/httpd/
drwxr-xr-x. 5 root root 105 Oct 22 23:40 /etc/httpd/
[Intensify@localhost ~]$ ls -ld /var/www/
drwxr-xr-x. 4 root root 33 Oct 22 23:40 /var/www/
```

Answer (score 0):

Check whether did you have any files available on the /var/www/html.

1. In centos the document directory structure of apache will be /var/www/html.
2. try to change the permission of /var/www/html to 0775.
3. Check index.html file is there inside the /var/www or /var/www/html in your httpd server document path.

Comment: I changed permission ton /html directory to 0775 `[Intens@localhost ~]$ ls -ld /var/www/html/
drwxrwxr-x. 2 root root 6 Oct  7 17:44 /var/www/html/`. I am trying to save index.html file in html/ folder. Still says I don't have permissions.

Answer (score 0):

I know the reason. Because the permission about the outermost layer directory.After I use chmod 775 to change the premission everything is work!

In this case you need check /var permission must match drwxrwxr-x then curl again!
use this command to check: ls -l /